# How can I launch Apple Maps on tap of a MKPointAnnotation Title?

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkannotation

I am allowing users to create an annotation on a `MKMapView`. I want the title of the annotation to be: `"Directions to Here"`. And when the user taps on the title, I want the Maps app to open and display the point so that the user can get directions.

My code for creating the annotation is here:

```
var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = location
annotation.title = "Directions to Here"
annotation.title. //Not sure what to put here to make the title a button
annotations.append(annotation)
map.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

Comment: I think this might get you started. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225296/how-can-i-add-a-button-to-mkpointannotation