# Adding an attribute to MKAnnotation

Tags: swift

I have this function:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!) {

    performSegueWithIdentifier("mapToCity", sender: self)
    var title = view.annotation.title
    var subtitle = view.annotation.subtitle
    var lat = view.annotation.coordinate.latitude
    var lng = view.annotation.coordinate.longitude
    var image = view.annotation.image
}
```

And I declared the annotation this way:

```
            var marker = CustomPointAnnotation()
            marker.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat.doubleValue, longitude: lng.doubleValue)
            marker.title = title.string
            marker.subtitle = subtitle.string
            marker.imageName = "marker.png"
            marker.image = "Test";
            mapView.addAnnotation(marker)
```

But the problem is that I can't call the variable `view.annotation.image` because the member image does not exist. So how do I add the member image so I can use that too?

Comment: Check out this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225296/how-can-i-add-a-button-to-mkpointannotation/28226174#28226174

Comment: No that's not really what I want unfortunately. It just shows how to add a button but what I want is to add extra information like `view.annotation.rate` `view.annotation.height` etc.