# Swift MapKit Annotation using coordinate from API not showing up on map

Tags: swift, mapkit

I used coordinate from API to put an annotation on map, but it didn't show up while:

1. I declared a new coordinate which is not from API, can show up on map.
2. I can print the coordinate form API, and the coordinate was fine.
3. I put mapView.addAnnotation() in DispatchQueue.main.async.

Can anyone tell me how to fix it? Thanks!
Here is my code:

```
extension LocationViewController: ParkProviderDelegate {
func didFetch(by provider: ParkProvider) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        let coordinate = self.provider.parks[0].coordinate
        self.mapView?.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}
```

Comment: set `annotation.coordinate = coordinate`

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225296

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    let coordinate = self.provider.parks[0].coordinate
    annotation.coordinate = coordinate
    annotation.title = "title"
    annotation.subtitle = "subtitle"
    self.mapView?.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```